# using smbget to download multiple files

Tags: download, samba, windows-server

I need to download multiple files from a video server. The files are available in following ways

- \\fileserver\directory\file1.txt
- \\fileserver\directory\file2.txt
- \\fileserver\directory\file3.txt

from a suse linux server I am using smbget like below

```
smbget smb://fileserver/directory/file1.txt smb://fileserver/directory/file2.txt smb://fileserver/directory/file3.txt

Username: domainname\user
password: ******
```

But it downloads only the first file whereas the man page, https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/smbget.1.html clearly says below

> smbget [-a, --guest] [-r, --resume] [-R, --recursive] [-u,
>   --username=STRING] [-p, --password=STRING] [-w, --workgroup=STRING] [-n, --nonprompt] [-d, --debuglevel=INT] [-D, --dots] [-P,
>   --keep-permissions] [-o, --outputfile] [-f, --rcfile] [-q, --quiet] [-v, --verbose] [-b, --blocksize] [-O, --stdout] [-?, --help]
>   [--usage] {smb://host/share/path/to/file} [smb://url2/] [...]

Isnt it pretty clear that multiple files can be given in a single command? why its not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have all the files in the same directory, you can use `-R` to recursively download the whole directory containing the files:

```
smbget -R smb://fileserver/directory
```